# Google calendar.events.list returns only the attendees 'Email'. displayName and other fields missing

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-calendar-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I have an application that is using Google API Nodejs client.
The call to `calendar.events.list({ ... });` returns a list of events for the user but it only gives but the 'attendees' array only has the 'email' and 'responseStatus' fields in it.

I want the attendee's name on my app instead of their email because it increases the usability (obviously).

When I look at the particular event in my Google Calendar, it shows the Names of the attendees with a GMail ID. So this means there has to be a way to get the displayName of the attendees with a GMail account.

Here is the code for the call to events.list:

```
const calendar = google.calendar( { version: 'v3', auth } );
calendar.events.list(
{
    calendarId:   'primary',
    timeMin:      startParam.toISOString(),
    timeMax:      endParam.toISOString(),
    maxResults:   999,
    singleEvents: true,
    orderBy:      'startTime',
    timeZone:     req.query.timeZone
},
(error: any, response: any) => {
    //CallBack
    if ( error ) {
        res.status(500).send( 'The post request returned an error: ' + error );
    }
    else {
        res.status(200).send(response.data.items);
    }
});
```

Comment: I think you have to specify the `displayName` when creating the event or adding the attendee through the API, if you want to have that field populated. If your application has access to the attendees' account data, though, you could access its `fullName`, which I think is very similar or the same as the `displayName`. Do you think that could be a valid workaround for your situation?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to the attendees' account data. Also, I am not creating the events through the API. I'm just reading whatever events there are for a user for the given day.

Comment: A follow up: If I have to access the attendees' account data, I have create a separate OAuth flow for each Gmail ID in the attendees array and access their userInfo, right?

Comment: If that's the case, I'm afraid you cannot retrieve the `displayName`. Also, regarding you're follow up, if you're an administrator, for example, you can access their data with only one OAuth flow. Are you an administrator?

Comment: I'm not sure what administrator here means exactly. The way that I am using the Google Calendar API is: I have the user's access token and refresh token from when they sign in and give permission to my app to access their calendar. Then, even when they're offline, I can use the access and refresh tokens to authenticate the user, and OAuth to authenticate my app and get the events. So I'm pretty sure that doesn't qualify me as an 'administrator', though I am unsure about the word 'administrator's' context here.

Comment: By `administrator` I mean your domain admin, which can access the [Admin console](https://support.google.com/a/answer/182076?hl=en). See [this](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33325?hl=en&ref_topic=9832445) and [this](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2405986?hl=en&ref_topic=9832445). If you authenticate as an admin user, you can access the data from any account in your domain. So, you're not an admin / don't have access to an admin account?

Comment: Oh yeah I am not an admin. There's actually no concept of an administrator since my app doesn't have a 'domain'.